# firefox destroy fonts after a form submission

Tags: php, html, firefox, encoding, persian

Currently I am developing a web site by php in Persian ( Farsi language ).The problem is when I submit a form in firefox all fonts get destroyed. like below pictures:
[image: before submiting]

[image: after submiting]

I have checked the code ( include meta tags and others thousands of times ) and it makes it more wierd that this happend only on firefox and no other browser after submission.Is there any bug related to firefox or am I supposed to change any attribute of form . 
I am quiet desperated . please help me if anyone has a clue.

Comment: Have you tried other persian fonts?

Comment: This has nothing to do with fonts. It’s a character encoding error. You need to provide some code that can be used to construct the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this issue out.
I used `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />`.
I replaced it with UTF8 header in PHP :
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 and problem solved.

I had another problem that solved with this change.My website pages loaded twice in firefox and its solved now.It seams that fire fox dont like that meta tag at all ;)

Answer (score 2):

One detail of your screenshot caught my attention:

[image]

[image]

This looks a bit like a LTR variant of UTF-8 BOM.

To quote from [Wikipedia Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

> A text editor or web browser interpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters "`ï»¿`" for this.

I would therefore assume you inject invalid text-fragments having such a BOM *inside* and existing HTML document (AJAX?), your Firefox browser detects that the document can't be valid Unicode any longer and therefore falls back to ISO-8859-1 which once was the default character encoding for all text documents on the internet.

As the CSS rules still apply, the LTR display was preserved, just the text-encoding meta-information was changed.

Please take care: Having the correct headers is one thing to signal the correct encoding, however it does not unburdened you from actually provide correctly encoded text-data.

I must admit, those BOMs can be pretty tricky, so they are easy to overlook.

**Solution:** Do not inject any BOM here. If you provide back HTML from a PHP file, check the PHP file that it doesn't use any BOMs.